# Django dynamic creation of table in database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically create table in database (SQLite3). What I'm trying to do is to get file from user and based on rows in file create table with the same amount of columns. Everything I found is from 6-10 years so it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: you want to create new table for each user who uploads the file or one file that forms the table?

Comment: One file creating new table.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are not finding many examples are Django is abstracting out raw SQL.

Have you looked at using Raw SQL queries, specifically [Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

```
table_name = 'Your_Name'
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(f"create table if not exists {table_name} ( id integer PRIMARY KEY )")
```

Will create a table called 'Your_Name' with a column called id, you will need to read the CSV, there is an example of how to do that [here](https://medium.com/@simathapa111/how-to-upload-a-csv-file-in-django-3a0d6295f624), if you follow that example you could add the DDL into `views.py`